# Modifying placement properties for labels using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, labeling

Does anyone know how to modify the location of a label programmatically?

I'd like to make the labels sit directly below the symbol!

Comment: Do you wish to modify the location of _individual_ labels, or to change the position preferences for a _layer's_ labels?

Comment: I'd like to change the position preferences for a layer's labels.

Comment: For anyone interested in a workaround, see answer to [this question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275705/can-i-use-arcpy-to-change-the-placement-properties-of-labels

Answer (score 4):

I've never tried this, but from the documentation it doesn't appear possible to change a layer's label positioning properties using arcpy.

The [layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000008000000) class provides access to that layers' [labelClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002t000000) - but from what I can see, this only gives the option to toggle labels on/off, change the expression, and set SQL queries. It doesn't appear to give access to the label positioning options.

You may need to resort to ArcObjects in order to access the full set of labelling properties. As the [Introduction to arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/) document says:

> Arcpy.mapping is not a replacement for ArcObjects but rather an
>   alternative for the different scenarios it supports. ArcObjects is
>   still necessary for finer-grain development and application
>   customization, whereas arcpy.mapping is intended for automating the
>   contents of existing map documents and layer files.

**Edit:** I haven't tried using ArcObjects to adjust the label placement, but it seems the [ILabelEngineLayerProperties2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/d/0012000006vq000000.htm) interface is the place to look. This interface has a property [BasicOverposterLayerProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/BasicOverposterLayerProperties_Property/0012000006vs000000/) which allows you to "specify how labels are placed relative to features."

The documentation from this point is a bit light/non-existent so you may need to do some experimentation.

Comment: So how do I use ArcObjects to modify the location of the labels?

Comment: Can you ask that as a separate question? (Stack Exchange is designed for one question and answer per thread. People will find this thread by searching on Labelling and ArcPy - you need to start a new thread for Labelling and ArcObjects)

Comment: That is what I was asking in my original question. Your answer didn't cover it.

Comment: "Does anyone know how to modify the location of a label using arcpy?"

Comment: So how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry if it seems like I'm deliberately being difficult - but Stack Exchange isn't designed like other sites - it's not a discussion forum but rather a Q&A site. So - the answer to your question about labelling and ArcPy seems to be "it's not possible". You need to post a new question asking how to do this specifically in ArcObjects. The reason Stack Exchange is set up this way is to make it easier for others to find answers to their questions in the future.